# Extracting data values from MATLAB meshgrid output

Tags: matlab

I need to extract data values for a particular coordinate from a meshgrid in MATLAB, my code is the following:

```
PaarX=Paar(:,1);
PaarX1=PaarX(1:20:length(PaarX));
PaarY=Paar(:,2);
PaarY1=PaarY(1:20:length(PaarY));
x=PaarX;
y=PaarY;
v=Paar(:,3);
[xi, yi]=meshgrid(PaarX1, PaarY1);
vq=griddata(x, y, v, xi, yi, 'cubic');
```

The `PaarX`, `PaarY` and `v` are the X, Y and Z values of the surface, with the Z values the values to be interpolated. `PaarX1` and `PaarY1` are the values used in the meshgrid with every 20th value taken (the array was too large before this). I need to extract interpolated Z values in `vq` from particular X and Y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question, you need this:

```
nx = 3; % <= length(PaarX1)
ny = 4; % <= length(PaarY1)
fprintf('the interpolated value at x=%g and y=%g is %g',PaarX1(nx),PaarY1(ny),vq(ny,nx))
```

Or you can transpose the matrix `vq`

```
vq = vq.';
fprintf('the interpolated value at x=%g and y=%g is %g',PaarX1(nx),PaarY1(ny),vq(nx,ny))
```

`vq(ny,nx)` (`y` is first) is because you use the `meshgrid` function. You can use access to a matrix element in the form `vq(nx,ny)` (`x` is first) for the `ndgrid` function (but I'm not sure that it works with `griddata`).

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Interpolation (line 18)
fprintf('the interpolated value at x=%g and y=%g is
%g',PaarX1(n1),PaarY1(n2),vq(n1,n2))

Comment: I think the above is because the index doesn't contain the X and Y coordinate values.

Comment: OK! I see you use `meshgrid`. I had corrected my answer.